# RoR: undefined method `new_user_invite' for InviteMailer:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I used the following tutorial on creating scoped invite (https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails) to create invite, user, group but ran into the above error and not sure how to solve it. Please bear in mind I am still learning RoR. Thanks.

I have the following code in invites_controller.rb

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @invite = Invite.new
  end

  def create
    @invite = Invite.new(invite_params) # Make a new Invite
    @invite.sender_id = current_user.id # set the sender to the current user
    if @invite.save
       InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver #send the invite data to our mailer to deliver the email
       flash[:notice] = "Thanks, invitation has successfully been sent"
       redirect_to user_groups_url
    else
       flash[:notice] =  "oh no, creating an new invitation failed"
       redirect_to invites_path
    end
  end

  private

    def invite_params
      params.require(:invite).permit(:email, :recipient_id, :user_group_id, :sender_id)
    end

end
```

Model for invite to send token

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord

  before_create :generate_token

  def generate_token
   self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([self.user_group_id, Time.now, rand].join)
  end


end
```

Not sure if the Route is complete?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :memberships
  resources :user_groups
  # mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  # devise_for :users
  # delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  default_url_options :host => "smtp.gmail.com"

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions',
      passwords: 'users/passwords',
      registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
  get 'static_pages/index'

  resources :invites

  namespace :admin, path: '/admin' do
    resources :users, except: [:show] do
      member do
        post :resend_invite
        post :enable
      end
    end
    resources :roles, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :new, :create]
    get "audits/index"
  end
end
```

view form to invite new user and existing users.

```
= simple_form_for @invite , :url => invites_path do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

  space-left3.space-below3
    = f.hidden_field :user_group_id, :value => @invite.user_group_id
    = f.input :email, placeholder: 'user@domain.com'
  .form-actions
    button.btn.btn-primary type="submit" Send
```

mailer/invite_mailer.rb

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def self.new_user_invite(invite, signup_url)
    subject    'Invite'
    recipients invite.recipient_email
    from       'example@gmail.com'
    body       :invite => invite, :signup_url => signup_url
    invite.update_attribute(:sent_at, Time.now)
  end

  def invite
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

mailer/application_mailer

```
 class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default from: 'from@example.com'
      layout 'mailer'
    end
```

Comment: Presumably, this is the offending line: `InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver`. If you had shown your `InviteMailer` class, we might be able to see that there is no `new_user_invite` method.

Comment: I used rails generate to create InviteMailer. Not sure how to def the new_user_invite in here.  Here it is:   class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.invite_mailer.invite.subject
  #
  def invite
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end

Comment: I can't tell for sure (it's best to put code in your question by using the `edit` link just under the tags), but it looks like the class in fact does not have the `new_user_invite` method. Perhaps add the code to your question so it's easier to see?

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Comment: Have your tried adding new_user_invite to your required params?

Comment: jvillian: I have updated the invite_mailer.rb and now I am getting undefined method `subject' for InviteMailer:Class. Please help. Thx

Comment: pretty nice example https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I can explain it, but for mailers we just define methods without class syntax. It is very convenient to think about mailer like about controller, they are very similar. Should be:

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def new_user_invite(invite, signup_url)
    @signup_url = signup_url
    invite.update_attribute(:sent_at, Time.now)
    mail(to: invite.email, subject: 'Invite')
  end
end
```

Now you need a view for email. Create a file called `new_user_invite.html.erb` in app/views/invite_mailer/. For simplicity it will be:

```
<p>Someone invited you to the project, please click link: @signup_url</p>
```

Also you need to change `new_user_registration_path` to `new_user_registration_url` in mailer call, to pass full link

You can read more about mailers in [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Comment: Vasilisa: Thank you so much, it worked. I spent a few hours on this and now I am able to move to the next step. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kourosh, happy to help you. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer if it helped

Comment: It definitely did and I did accept as a working answer. let me know if the acceptance is not showing. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kourosh looks like you only voted up the answer. It should have green checkmark after accepting

Answer (score 0):

To create the `new_user_invite` as a class method on `InviteMailer`, you do:

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  class << self 

    def new_user_invite(invite, path)
      ... do stuff
    end

  end

  def invite
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end

end
```

Or,

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def self.new_user_invite(invite, path)
    ... do stuff
  end

  def invite
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end

end
```

Which you use is a matter of personal preference.

I want to note that [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag) wishes to say:

> I am one of those Ruby Purists who likes to point out that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. I am perfectly fine, though, with using the term *class method* colloquially, **as long as it is fully understood by all parties that it is a colloquial usage**. In other words, if you *know* that there is no such thing as a class method and that the term "class method" is just short for "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of `Class`", then there is no problem. But otherwise, I have only seen it obstruct understanding.

Let it be fully understood by all parties that the term *class method* is used above in its colloquial sense.

Comment: My problem is the "....do stuff" part. would it be the following as an example:   subject    'Invitation'
    recipients invitation.recipient_email
    from       'foo@example.com'
    body       :invitation => invitation, :signup_url => signup_url
    invitation.update_attribute(:sent_at, Time.now)
  end

Comment: One more thing, do I need model for mailer as the following? class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def invitation(invitation, signup_url)
    subject    'Invitation'
    recipients invitation.recipient_email
    from       'foo@example.com'
    body       :invitation => invitation, :signup_url => signup_url
    invitation.update_attribute(:sent_at, Time.now)
  end
end

Comment: "How do you set up an ActionMailer?" is an entirely different question than "How do I solve the `undefined method 'new_user_invite' for InviteMailer:Class` error?" The tutorial you're following asserts "The invitation mailer is very basic", so perhaps take a look at the Guide and see where that takes you.